# Get multiple checked checkbox values in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My code is below:

On page i have a products list with checkbox, code & name of that product.
When selecting multiple checkboxes, on submit click, i need to get the selected checkbox values & save it in the DB.

Product View Model class:

```
public class ProductVM
{
 public ProductVM()
    {
        this.ProductsList = new List<Product>();
    }

public List<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }

public class Product
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

}
```

Product Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
var model = new ProductVM();

        var product1 =  new ProductVM.Product
            {
                Code = "Product1",
                Name = "Apple"
            };


        var product2 =  new ProductVM.Product 
            {
                Code = "Product2",
                Name = "Banana"
            };

        model.ProductsList.Add(Product1);
        model.ProductsList.Add(Product2);

        return View(model);
     }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductVM model)
{
if (model.ProductsList.Any(m => m.Selected))  
        {
           //How to get the selected Code & Name here
        }
}
```

Product View:

```
@model ProductVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   foreach (var item in Model.ProductsList)
   {
        @Html.CheckBox("IsSelected", item.IsSelected) 
        @Html.Label(item.Code)
        @Html.Label(item.Name)
   }
   <input type="submit" />
 }
```

Comment: create the same name for your checkboxes, and put ids into Value attribute -  then on submit you will get them comma - separated

Comment: how can i get it in the model itself n not use the form collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use `for` instead of `foreach`. Otherwise Razor won't generate the proper field names. Second, you need hidden inputs for the `Code` and `Name` properties so these will get posted back:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProductsList.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductsList[i].Code)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductsList[i].Name)
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ProductsList[i].IsSelected)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductsList[i].Code)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductsList[i].Name)
    </label>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To demo my code from my comment to question- You can get idea from it

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.FocusesList)
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="@item.ConfigurationId" name="FocusList" id="FocusList" /> @item.Value.Name
    </label>
}
```

After submit you have all checked values split by comma in Request["FocusList"]